# How can I associate dll files with nunit-x86.exe (instead of nunit.exe)?

Tags: nunit

I am working on a VISTA (x64) system.

My problem:
 Double clicking x86 .dll file does not start nunit-x86.exe

Background:
 My build creates example.dll (x86) with nunit tests.

WORKING Workflow:
* Start nunit-x86.exe
* DLL file is loaded, GUI is showing and running tests, everything o.k.

FAILING Workflow:
* Double click example.dll, FAILS

I do not describe the error message here, because I already know, that this error is caused by the fact, that double clicking the .dll starts "nunit.exe".

The context menu ("Open with") dialog allows me to "Browse" to "nunit-x86.exe" and select it, but this does not change the behaviour when double clicking example.dll.

Clarification: I browse to
   C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.3\bin\net-2.0\nunit-x86.exe

"assoc" and "ftype" neither show "dllfile" nor a "nunit" application anywhere. Since the context menu already shows me, that example.dll is associated by default to NUnit (I only see the Nunit bitmap), I do not want to use "assoc".

Can anybody explain, how to associate nunit-x86.exe to dll files (without using "assoc").

Best Regards
Heinrich

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/69758-default-programs.html

Comment: Thank you for this link.

When I mentioned "Open with" in my initial post - it was exactly "method 2" described in your link.

To clarify:
I am absolutely able to associate NUnit with ".dll", but...
...also I specify the nunit-x86.exe path apparently nunit.exe is associated.

When checking the list of candidates I only see the Icon "NUnit", but I cannot see what specific executable is actually associated.

Since the behaviour (error) is the same afterwards - I suspect, that "nunit.exe" is associated.

I my opinion it must have something to do with the fact, that this is vista x64.

Comment: Typo in my comment (sorry): ...**although** I specify the nunit-x86.exe path, apparently ...

Comment: Did you select "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"? in the "Open With" dialog?If it's still not working, you could try looking in the registry under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FilesExts\.dll, in case something has gone wrong there. I have Progid="Applications\nunit-x86.exe" under the UserChoice key. I have both nunit.exe and nunit-x86.exe listed under OpenWithList, but nunit-x86.exe comes first in MRUList.

Comment: Thank you PhilMY for your post - I did not check the answers for a while (since I found a workaround) - but will check your proposals.